# Flatten an array within a table which might be NULL or empty in presto

Tags: sql, arrays, presto, flatten, trino

I have the following table which I'm using in my sql query.

[image]

And I would like to turn it to the following shape

[image]

How should I do that? I have used unnest and cross join . Because of the empty array, I didn't get the whole view.

Comment: . . Edit your question and include the query you are using *as text*.  If you cannot figure out how to format it, then you can add it and someone will fix the formatting.

Comment: Sorry in the first row grade=1

Answer (score 5):

You can use `UNNEST` in the context of a `LEFT JOIN`:

```sql
WITH t(v) AS (VALUES 
    ARRAY[1,2],
    NULL,
    ARRAY[3,4],
    ARRAY[]
)
SELECT e
FROM t LEFT JOIN UNNEST(t.v) AS u(e) ON true
```

This was added in [Trino 319](https://trino.io/docs/current/release/release-319.html) ([formerly known as Presto SQL](https://trino.io/blog/2020/12/27/announcing-trino.html))

If you're not on a recent version, you can substitute with this:

```
...
FROM t CROSS JOIN UNNEST(if(t.v IS NULL OR cardinality(t.v) = 0, ARRAY[NULL], t.v)) AS u(e)
```